# Can i define nested array objects in swagger 2.0

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, swagger-editor

We are using Swagger 2.0 for our documentation. We are Pro-grammatically creating swagger 2.0 spec straight out our data design documents.

Our Model is very complex and nested. I would like to understand can we define nested array objects defined inline.

for e.g :

```
{
    "definitions": {
        "user": {
            "type": "object",
            "required": ["name"],
            "properties": {
                "name": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "address": {
                    "type": "array",
                    "items": {
                        "type": "object",
                        "properties": {
                            "type": {
                                "type": "string",
                                "enum": ["home",
                                "office"]
                            },
                            "line1": {
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                        },
                        "Person": {
                            "type": "object",
                            "properties": {
                                "name": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

We have many cases where we encounter this in our model and defining a #ref is not an option that we want to consider at this time. We need this to handled inline.

As per the following post : https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-editor/issues/603#even`enter code here`t-391465196 looks like its not supported to handle nested array objects defined inline.

Since lot of big enterprise's have a very complex data model we would like to have this  this feature to be supported in swagger 2.0 spec.

Is there any thought on this feature to be added.

Comment: Looks like this question rather belongs to the swagger homepage / forum / bugtracker.

Comment: Many frameworks will create `$ref` schemas for you automatically.  Can you share more of why that's not possible from a modeling point of view?

Comment: @fehguy can you please point us to some frameworks that will create $ref schemas.

Comment: Well, the swagger-supported `swagger-jaxrs` will do this.  If you have a property which is a complex type, the `$ref` will automatically be created.

Comment: Check this URL, it's not marked as solved, but I think it's fine:
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19585581/how-to-describe-a-model-in-swagger-for-an-array-with-simple-objects)

Answer (score 3):

You document is just invalid and this is not about nested arrays: the property `Person` is not allowed in a Swagger 2.0 schema inside `items`.

The only allowed properties in a [schema](http://swagger.io/specification/#schemaObject) are: `$ref`, `format`, `title`, `description`, `default`, `multipleOf`, `maximum`, `exclusiveMaximum`, `minimum`, `exclusiveMinimum`, `maxLength`, `minLength`, `pattern`, `maxItems`, `minItems`, `uniqueItems`, `maxProperties`, `minProperties`, `required`, `enum`, `additionalProperties`, `type`, `items`, `allOf`, `properties`, `discriminator`, `readOnly`, `xml`, `externalDocs`, `example`.