# Swagger - API payload as formData of object of arrays

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

```
/api/create:
    post:
      summary: ---
      description: ----
      parameters:
        - in: formData
          name: products
          description: 'Array of key value pairs'
          required: true
          type: array
          items:
            type: object
            properties:
              id: 
                type: string
```

This is giving error [image]

My goal is to accept input as an array of object.Something like `[{id:"sdsd"},{id:"dd"}]`

Comment: Does your API expect JSON (`application/json`, like in your example in the last paragraph) or form data (`application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data`)?

Comment: @Helen `application/json`. I think it's because of formData

Comment: _"I think it's because of formData"_ - yes, you need to use an `in: body` parameter instead - see the [linked Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19585581/113116).